# ASP.NET MVC and WebAPI on same domain

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-web-api

I have an MVC application hosted on www.example.com on a dedicated virtual server.
I now have a new WebAPI application that has it's own web.config, token authentication and can not really inherit from the MVC config.

Can I have the WebAPI running on the subdomain api.example.com? 
If not is there any other way to have them both working separatelly but using the same domain?

Any suggestion is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, using subdomains is the only good way to have the applications work separately on the same IIS. Just make sure to use different application pools for each one.

Comment: in the end this is what i did, the hosting configured a sub domain, worked perfectly..